# How to adjust column width in Excel (.Width not .ColumnWidth)

Tags: excel, vba

When I use the code

```
ActiveSheet.Range("b:Az").ColumnWidth = 5
MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range("d1").ColumnWidth
```

it shows 5, but when using

```
ActiveSheet.Range("b:Az").ColumnWidth = 5
MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range("d1").Width
```

it shows 30

I know that the two properties are not the same (for some reason that I can't understand), but I want actually to adjust the property `.Width` not `.ColumnWidth` for some calculations in my code, but Excel refuses to adjust `.Width` property and shows Error '1004' (unable to adjust with property) when I run the following code:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("b:Az").Width = 5
```

so, how to adjust `.Width` property?

Comment: Range.Width is the width of a range in points, it is Read-only. Calculate the ratio `ratio = ColumnWidth/Width` and set `Columnwidth = newWidth * ratio`.

Answer (score 0):

width can not be set  -see here
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.width][1]

width gives you the width in pixel.

columnWidth can be set, according to ms-page: One unit of column width is equal to the width of one character in the Normal style